# Unable to access linkedin via VNC on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, linkedin-api, vnc-viewer

I have setup an EC2 instance with VNC GUI access to it. While browsing LinkedIn from the EC2 instance, I am unable to open custom LinkedIn URLs, i.e. URL of a specific user (lets say https://np.linkedin.com/in/abc123). I have also opened port 443, 8080 from security groups. I get ping reply from np.linkedin.com though. 
Can anyone guide me what could have gone wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get? Is it 503? It is possible that linked in is blocking aws ip space from accessing certain parts of their site due to abuse.

Comment: Tor exit nodes run into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can verify that **unauthenticated access** to LinkedIn from an Amazon EC2 instance does not display user information (and the URL mentions something about `sentinel_org_blocked`.

I suspect that LinkedIn is intentionally blocking access from the Amazon EC2 IP address range to prevent information scraping. It **works successfully** if the user is logged into LinkedIn.