# Python request.get() timeout when executed from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, https, amazon-vpc

From an AWS Lambda function, using Python code, I'm trying to make a `request.get("https://linkedin.com")`, and sometimes I receive a timeout from the Lambda, and other times the following error message: `[ERROR] ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`.

The Lambda security group has all outbound traffic open, and I have tested a `curl` from another machine in the same subnet as the Lambda ([request.get method is not working for few specific websites in AWS Lambda Python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77301625/request-get-method-is-not-working-for-few-specific-websites-in-aws-lambda-python)), and it works perfectly. What could be happening?

Comment: Have you increased timeout in lambda Function configuration? As default timeout is 3secs, You have to increase as per your functionality. Maximum timeout Limit is 15min

Comment: similar question asked before in stackoverflow maybe this can help u, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31822414/10929840

Comment: When I try to make a requests.post to log in to LinkedIn, I also get a timeout. How do I log in then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Lambda security group has all outbound traffic open,

So you have it deployed to a VPC

> and I have tested a curl from another machine in the same subnet as the Lambda

The machine you tested `curl` from probably has a public IP address. A Lambda function in a VPC never gets a public IP address. To provide a Lambda function in a VPC access to a service on the Internet, you have to add a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to your VPC, configure some private subnets with a route to that NAT Gateway, and configure the Lambda function to *only* run in those private subnets.

If your Lambda function doesn't actually need to access anything inside the VPC, then it is a much better option to simply configure the Lambda function to run without a VPC.